# How host defends against S. pneumoniae capsule?

Tags: microbiology, inflammation, pathogenesis, host-pathogen-interaction

The host response involves at least phagocytosis and probably localised acute inflammatory response at least after the colonisation.

I am thinking how the host can defend against pneumolysin which helps the streptococcus pneumoniae invasion.

How can the host defend against Streptococcus pneumoniae capsule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the two papers listed below, this is mostly done by a neutrophilic inflammatory response. The response is regulated by mechanisms of the innate immune system and is mediated by receptor like TLR2, TLR4 and SIGN-R1.

- [Role of Dectin-2 in the host defense against Streptococcus
  pneumoniae infection](http://www.jimmunol.org/cgi/content/meeting_abstract/188/1_MeetingAbstracts/45.8)
- [Dectin-2-dependent NKT cell activation and serotype-specific antibody
  production in mice immunized with pneumococcal polysaccharide
  vaccine.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/24205278)

There are a few papers which go deeper (reviews, so you will probably have to go through the reference lists):

- [Mechanisms of host defense against infection with Streptococcus
  pneumoniae.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/1571441)

This paper mentions specific antibodies later on in the reaction and finally the opsonization by immune cells.

These two papers tal specifically about pneumolysin:

- [Pneumococcal virulence factors and host immune responses to them.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/7588820)
- [Pneumolysin as a vaccine and drug target in the prevention and
  treatment of invasive pneumococcal disease.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/15995579)

Comment: This seems to be localised acute inflammation what they describe. Probably, first fibrous type of acute inflammation.

Comment: @Masi I expanded my answer.